# What is the relationship between these two shapes?

Tags: pattern, visual

Based on the relationship between the shapes in the top row, fill the question mark with a shape from the right.

[image]

Source: *Iranian Ph.D. university entrance exam 2016*

Comment: **Note to solvers:** those symbols before the brackets are the Arabic symbols for 1, 2, 3, 4 - don't try analysing them to wonder if they tell us anything about the solution(s).

Comment: @Rand Finding that point could be part of the puzzle.

Comment: Wouldn't people in Iran already know that though?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sure they know! I meant at here, it could be part of the puzzle because one can read the "Source" and guess that they are just numbers in another script. Besides, they are not much different from English ones. Interestingly Latin numbers are exactly the ones that the Persian mathematics Kharazmi introduced (from Indian) in his great book Algebra (now most people consider both the numbers and algebra Arabic!).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually [Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) are just the regular digits 0 to 9. What you're refering to is the [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) aka Indic numerals. And the numbers used in the question are not even Eastern Arabic numerals, they're a variant (called Pseudo-Arabic variant) used in the Persian alphabet (notice [the difference in 4 for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals#Numerals)).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah, I know 0-9 are actually Arabic and the other ones are more Indian and just used in modern Arabic, but I didn't want to confuse things :-) The digits seen here are the ones used by (many) Arabic writers, which is what matters. (Didn't know the Pseudo-Arabic thing, but I'm not surprised that Persian uses slightly different digits to Arabic, since their way of using the letters is also slightly different.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> the top right, since the dots have been rotated two spaces counter-clockwise around the perimeter.

Comment: By the way, the top right is 2.

Comment: @Ahmad: spoiler